# GRE Permutation and geometry question

Tags: geometry, permutations, gre-exam

1. if you join all the vertices of a heptagon, how many quadrilaterals will you get?
2. How many heptagons can be drawn by joining the vertices of a polygon with 10 sides?
3. A polygon has 20 diagonals,how many sides does it have ?
   Are there are formula showing relation between diagonal and no of sides of a polygon?

These two questions are similar.
Any clues to help me solve the problem.

Comment: For 3., have you tried drawing different polygons and counting up the number of diagonals and looking for a pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to choose 4 vertices from 7 vertices of Heptagon. How do you do that?
2. Same as 1, you need to select 7 out of 10.
3. No of distance diagonals is n(n-3)/2; you can do this if you can get above 2.

Comment: thanks for number 3 but i could not figure out 1 and 2,

Comment: Its simple combination problem, you need to select 4 out of 7, it 7C4. {as the order doesn't matter}

Comment: @sonam: Try reading [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). User33263 is suggesting (correctly) that you want $\binom74$ and $\binom{10}7$.

Comment: But there will be many quadrilaterals that won't have vertices on the Heptagon.